# Getting "Cannot find class in classpath" while running TestNG test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

When I am running the TestNG test, I am getting the "Cannot find class in classpath: com.crm.homePage.VerifyLoginPageIncorrectCred" error.
Previously I was using the latest TestNG version and was getting the same error. Now I am using TestNG version 6.11.0and the problem remains the same.

What could be the problem? I tried other resolutions provided in the StackOverflow, but none of them seems to be helpful.

Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image: TestNG Error Screenshot]

Comment: You can clear your project in eclipse

Comment: Well, I did that by going to Project > Clean, but that doesn't work.

Comment: See the `!` on your project? Check your build path, tell us what is causing that `!`.

Comment: right click on your project--> maven--> updatemaven

Comment: Thanks, @VinceEmigh for noticing that. I checked the error logs and found that some of the dependencies jar files were invalid. So changed the version of the jar file. Now it's working.

Comment: @Shashank - You should perhaps answer your question and accept the answer as well, so that the question gets closed.